# How to shrink a root partion from remote?

Tags: 12.04, server, remote, partitioning

I've searched for a way, but there hasn't been a definite way to do this.  So...

I want to install Debian next to a Ubuntu 12.04.1 install on an old Mac Mini I have colocated with MacMiniColo.  I have plenty of room (500 gig HD), but I need to ether:

- Remove the swap partition and install Debian in it...
- ...or, resize the main Ubuntu partition (which is root, formatted EXT4), of which 60 gigs are used.

I want to do the latter, shrinking it down by 80 gigs to safely put in a Debian install.  Of course, I'll back everything up beforehand.  But this means needing to shrink a partition ether live or be triggered on reboot (the Raspberry Pi's Raspbian offshoot of Debian Wheezy does this).

***Going to the colo facility and shoving in a liveCD is NOT an option!*** I'm in Baltimore, the colo is in Las Vegas, and I don't want to have a tech there run gparted on it if I can help it.

Ether way, I have to be dangerous.  It's because Canonical worries me now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have a tech at the colo facility boot into a live CD and enable SSH. You could then SSH into the server and run gparted from your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

The swap partition route you mentioned is probably the best way to go.  Install a minimal system there with `debootstrap` and reboot into it, then you can use a combination of `resize2fs` and `parted` to shrink the filesystem, then delete and recreate the partition with a smaller size ( at least what you shrank the filesystem to ) and the exact same start sector it had before.

Of course, this is very risky without any alternate means of gaining console control of the system and/or being able to force it to netboot to recover should you do something wrong, so you likely will end up having to go to the facility or call and have someone there boot the machine from a known system that has remote access enabled anyway.